# Action refuses to return the boolean value

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have the standard `destroy` action:

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Quiz::find($id)->delete();
}
```

Which is accessed by the following AJAX call:

```javascript
// The CSRF token is included automatically!
$.ajax({
    url: /quiz/10,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_method: 'DELETE'},
    success: function(response){
        if(response){
            // do stuff..
        }
    }
});
```

### The problem

When the AJAX call is made, chrome console shows the following error:

[image]

Strange thing is, that **everything works if I remove the `return`,** but I need the status code to be returned. Can somebody explain why is this happening? Or, at least, how to debug this problem?

### Update

Everything starts working properly if I rewrite the `destroy` action like this:

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Quiz::delete($id);
}
```

But I still can't understand why doesn't the first action work?

Comment: so, have you checked the logs?

Comment: @Alexander Lomia, Quiz is probably not found with that ID, so You are getting `Trying to get property of non-object` error...

Comment: @zerkms Actually, by asking how to debug this problem, I was anticipating that someone will explain where / how to find the logs

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys Than why does it get deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't return a Boolean value (`Quiz::find($id)->delete();` returns `true` or `false`), It's better to do something like below,

```
$deleted =  Quiz::find($id)->delete(); //this will return true/false

return response()->json(['success' => $deleted]);
```

In the frontend

```
$.ajax({
    url: /quiz/10,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_method: 'DELETE'},
    success: function(response){
        if(response.success == true){
            // do stuff..
        } else {
            // something went wrong when deleting the record.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. In fact, returning only a boolean value is possible, please check the updated question

Comment: `destroy()` will return `1` or `0`, while `delete()` returns `true` or `false` that's why `Quiz::destroy($id)` works because (`0/1`) not treated as boolean.

Comment: I see. Indeed just returning a boolean value was causing the error. Your solution works like a charm, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `Trying to get property of non-object` error occurs.
Try this

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Quiz::destroy($id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works (if `destroy` is swapped by `delete`), but I still can't understand why didn't my action work and what's the difference between these two variations of it

Comment: cause when you first time call your url `/quiz/10`, ` Quiz::find($id)` returns model instance and you perform `delete` method on it. Further times `Quiz::find($id)` returns null, cause record with this id doesn't exists anymore. So you try call `delete` function on non-object

Comment: But isn't the url called only once?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public function destroy($id) {

    $quiz =  Quiz::find($id);
    $quiz->delete();

    if ($quiz) {
        return response()->json('true');
    } else {
        return response()->json('false');
    }
}
```

the response is oviously a json that contains true if the quiz has been deleted or false in case of error

im not good at js but :

```
$.ajax({
    url: /quiz/10,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_method: 'DELETE'},
    success: function(response){
        if(response == 'true'){ // should work i guess
            // do stuff..
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. The `if($quiz)` statement will always evaluate to true in this case. In regards to the javascript code, both mine and your AJAX calls are exactly the same

Comment: The `$quiz` model is always preserved after you delete it, so when for example you run the following commands: `$quiz->delete()` and `$quiz->save()` the new record will be created. The `if($quiz->delete())` would work perfectly in this case

Comment: what you are saying makes sense ! but it worked for me, anyway i hope u find tge solution